# django error module not found

Tags: python, django

I have an error in Django. I was learning django through djangobook.com. I made admin page as it was written in that book and the admin page was successfully displayed.Then, I was told to made `admin.py` in the folder that was created by `startapp` and I made admin.py and pasted the code.The code is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

But, after that when I again tried to run admin page then the error appeared mentioning these things.
    Import at /admin/
    No module named books.model

I was doing as the book made me to do but I got this error.So, what is the solution for this?

Comment: if your `/books/` folder doesn't contain an empty `__init__.py` file, you should create it and try again.

Comment: You forgot to write `models` and instead in  your file you have `books.model`

Comment: Actually file is books.models but i typed incorrectly as books.model.

Comment: Please, write your files tree

Answer (score 0):

Does the error mention `books.model` or `books.models`. You might fix it by replacing `books.model` to `books.models` in your import statement.

Comment: the error mentioned books.models and i replaced it by books.model but still the error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try "**from .models import**" instead of "**from mysite.books.models import**".

I was just having the same issue, and this solved it for me.